# Windows Live Messenger redist for remote deployment

Tags: outlook, deployment, msi, messenger

I can't seem to find the redist package for this software. download.live.com loads an exe that downloads appropriate packages on the fly, but I would like the MSIs for Messenger and the Outlook Connector.   Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it dump the installation files into a temp folder you can harvest to get the msi etc?

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at the notes section [here](http://www.appdeploy.com/packages/detail.asp?id=1954) at appdeploy to locate the full install package.